# Shortest Distance Between Skew Lines with Basic Geometry

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry, solid-geometry

Cube **ABCD.EFGH** have side length s cm, calculate the shortest distance of segment line **AH** and **DG** without involving vector (or even partial differentiation) and only using basic geometry (such as pythagorean theorem, trigonometry, etc).

My work: Find the plane which is perpendicular to **DG** which is **ADEH** (Because **ADEH** is perpendicular to **DCGH** which **DG** lies on), **ADEH** intersect **DG** at line **AD** on point **D**. So i thought the distance between those two skew lines is perpendicular distance from **D** to **AH** . Im using $base.height = base.height$ to find perpendicular distance from **D** to **AH**,which is $\frac{S}{\sqrt{2}}$. But when i checked using vector my answer is wrong and the correct answer is $\frac{S}{\sqrt{3}}$.

What's going on ? which line segment is the correct shortest distance ? and how does skew lines distance are calculated without vector ? please show me how did you do it, pretty please.

[image: Cube]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $AH||BG$ and $HF||DB$, we obtain: $(AHF)||(DBG)$.

Id est, our distance it's just the distance between planes: $(AHF)$ and $(DBG).$

But $\overrightarrow{EC}$ it's a normal to both planes.

Thus, the needed distance is equal to $$\frac{1}{3}EC=\frac{s\sqrt3}{3}=\frac{s}{\sqrt3}.$$

Comment: Yes, this is what i need to see, so i thought we would need to make a perpendicular plane, but instead it need to be parallel

Comment: @Tobi123 It was a hint only. I am waiting for  your questions.

Comment: Well that's all, i just want to know where is my mistake

Comment: Ahmed has also given me a hint on how the distance between skew lines change (with visualisation)

Comment: This is nice! technically, @Michael Rozenberg translated the distance between the two lines to a distance between two planes. The questions are why do the planes $AHF$ and $DBG$ cut the line $EC$ in three equal lengths and why does this translation guarantee the smallest distance?

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam Take a parallelogram $EGCA$, $M$ is a midpoint of $EG$ and $N$ is a midpoint of $AC$. Also, let $EC\cap AM=\{P\}$ and $EC\cap GN=\{Q\}$. Thus, $EP=PQ=QC$ because $P$ and $Q$ are gravitation centers of $\Delta AEG$ and $\Delta AGC$ respectively.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg So, $EP + PQ + QC = \sqrt{3}s$ and $EP = PQ = QC$. Three questions: How do we know that $P$ and $Q$ are the gravitational centers of the triangles $\Delta AEG$ and $\Delta AGC$? Why is $EC$ normal to $AM$ and to $NG$? Does this translation of distance between the two lines $AH$ and $DG$ to the distance between the planes $AHF$ and $DBG$ guarantee the smallest distance, because $PQ$ is normal to both planes? Like $PQ$ is **the** distance?

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam Let $K$ be a midpoint of $EC$. Thus, $AM$ and $EK$ are medians of $\Delta AEG$. For $Q$ it's a similar. Also, $EC\perp(AHF)$ because $EC\perp HF$ and $EC\perp AH$. For example, $HF\perp EG$ and $HF\perp AE,$ which says $HF\perp(AEGC),$ which gives $HF\perp EC.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Right, I see now, that $P;Q$ are the intersections of means $AM, EK; GN, CK$ of triangles $\Delta AEG; \Delta ACG$  and are therefore centroids or gravitational centers of the triangles. How is this possible, that $EC\perp HE$ and $EC\perp AH$?

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam By the criterion: If $a\subset \pi$, $b\subset\pi$, $a\cap b=\{C\}$, $h\perp a$ and $h\perp b$, so $h\perp\pi.$ Actually, $h\perp\pi$ iff for all $a\subset\pi$ we have $h\perp a$. This a definition, but the criterion is better.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ok, I get it, you mean if a line $h$ is perpendicular to two lines $a$ and $b$ in a plane $\pi$, then this line $h$ is perpendicular to the whole plane $h\perp\pi$. This is logical, because a plane is made out of two lines. I think you changed $EC \perp HE$ to $EC \perp HF$ in a previous comment, but it doesn't matter, I get the point. So: $(EC \perp HF) \land (EC \perp AH) \Rightarrow EC \perp AHF$. This is nice and I get the concept why $EC$ is normal to the plane $AHF$, but why are the following two statements true: $EC \perp HF $  and  $EC \perp AH$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Maybe $EC \perp HF $ I can imagine/validate mechanically by moving the diagonal $EC$ and letting $E$ touch the middle point of the line $HF$, then we get a "T", but what about $EC \perp AH$? similar?!... Is there another (easier) way to see that two 3D lines are perpendicular to each other (without using the scalar product!)?...

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam See my previous comment. It's a theorem of a solid geometry. If $h\perp a$, $h\perp b$, $a\cap b=\{C\}$, $a\subset\pi$ and $b\subset\pi$ so $h\perp\pi.$ The proof is based on the congruence of triangles, but it takes a lot of place for write. By this theorem I proved that $EC\perp HF$. The proof that $EC\perp AH$ is a similar. There is a way by using vectors, but it's not geometry already.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg ok, if you used $a \subset\pi, b\subset \pi, a\cap b = \{C\}, h \perp a, h \perp b \rightarrow h \perp \pi $ to show that $EC \perp HF$, then what do $a,b,h,C,\pi$ stand for in the context of our example? $h=EC$? $\pi = HFA$?

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam  $\pi$ is a plane, $a$, $b$ and $h$ are lines.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes, I got that, what do $a,b$ and $C$ stand for in the context of our example means which lines are meant by $a,b$ and which intersection point $C$ of $a,b$ is meant with respect to the letters in our example? I can't see how it is possible to prove $EC \perp HF$ and $EC \perp AH$ with the help of this criterion, because this criterion is just saying, that when a line is perpendicular to two lines, that span a plane, then this line is also perpendicular to the plane spanned by the two lines.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Maybe it's still possible to prove that $EC \perp HF$ and $EC \perp AH$ with that criterion, but I can't see it yet

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam I proved before that $EC\perp HF$. See my third comment.  The proof of $EC\perp AH$ is the same.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg in your third comment you wrote: Also, $EC\perp(AHF)$ because $EC \perp HF$ and $EC \perp AH$. But for $EC \perp HF$ and $EC \perp AH$ there was no reasoning, why these statements are true. It's alright, I believe you!

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam Read in this comment after my words "for example". I wait your questions.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Alright, so because $HF$ is perpendicular to $AEGC$ (which is intuitive in this cube situation), we get that $HF$ is perpendicular to every line in the plane $AEGC$, also $HF \perp EC$. Nice!

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam Yes, of course!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg can you solve another coordinate-less 3D geometry for me ? here's the link : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332016/angle-between-two-planes-no-vector-and-coordinates-allowed-only-allowed-to-use
please i need to know how it's done.

Comment: @Tobi123 Yes, of course! But later. I am very busy now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is some easier way than differentiation, because questions like this are asked when the topic's name is differentiation. So here is the way to solve:

[image: Cube]

Imagine two opposite vertices of the cube are moving towards each other. Then these would be the vertices of a smaller cube inside of the original cube. The diagonal of the smaller cube is a distance between the two red lines and this distance or cube diagonal $D$ can be calculated with a geometry formula (3D pythagoras)

$$\begin{align*}D(h) &= \sqrt{(s-h)^2 + (s-h)^2 + (s-2h)^2} \\&= \sqrt{2(s-h)^2 + (s-2h)^2}\\&= \sqrt{6h^2-8hs+3s^2} \end{align*}$$

Now we ask for which $0 \leq h \leq \frac{s}{2}$ does $D(h)$ become the smallest possible $D(h)$. We need the first derivative of $D(h)$. The first derivative of a function $D(h)$ that looks like this $\sqrt{f(h)}$ is something that looks like this $\dfrac{f'(h)}{2\sqrt{f(h)}}$. Here we have $f(h) =6h^2-8hs+3s^2 $ and $f'(h)= 12h-8s$. In total we have

$$D'(h) = \dfrac{12h-8s}{2\sqrt{6h^2-8hs+3s^2}} $$

We then set $D'(h)=0$ to find the values of $h$ at which $D(h)$ has a max or a min value. Set $D'(h)=0$ and get $h=\frac{2}{3}s$. This is the only value for $h$, that makes $D'(h)=0$. So, the solution for the minimal distance is $$D\left(h=\frac{2}{3}s\right)= \sqrt{6\left(\dfrac{2}{3}s\right)^2-8\left(\dfrac{2}{3}s\right)s+3s^2}=\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Seems like basic geometry (with pythagorean) for 3D distances isnt really taught much in other countries, maybe it's even already forgotten. But people from my country was really able to use basic geometry to do this somehow