# Angle Between Two Planes (No Vector and Coordinates Allowed, Only Allowed to Use Non-Coordinate Geometry Tricks)

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

Cube $ABCD.EFGH$ have side length 6 units. P is the midpoint of $EH$, Q is the midpoint of $AD$, the angle between $BFPQ$ and $BDG$ is $\lambda$.

My attempt :

1) Because the line of intersection is outside the cube, i translated $BFPQ$ 3 units forward (from my point of view) so it become $DHP'Q'$ and the line intersection after translation is $DO$.

2) I calculated the distance from $B$ to $DO$ and distance from $Q'$ to $DO$, because in order to find the angle between two plane (without relying on normal vector) you must find 2 lines perpendicular to the line of intersection, Those 2 perpendicular lines in this case are $BO$ and $Q'U$

3) When i checked in GeoGebra it turns out that $BO$ and $Q'U$ are skew to each other. That's what caused my answer to be wrong.

My question is : How do i avoid the 2 lines perpendicular to the lines of intersection being skew to each other (avoid $BO$ and $Q'U$ being skew) ? and if i have to translate the skew lines how do i figure out how far do i need to translate one of the line so that the two lines aren't skew anymore ? is there any other easier way to do this ? of course without vector and coordinate.

[image: Cube]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines must be perpendicular to the line of intersection at the same point. In your case, the simplest thing to do is drawing a perpendicular $UV$ on plane $BDG$ (I don't know if point $V$ in your figure is the one I mean) and compute $\lambda=\angle Q'UV$.

EDIT.

Computing $UV$ and $Q'V$ is not difficult:

- in rectangle $DQ'P'H$ you have $UQ'=3\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}}$ and $DU=\frac{5\sqrt6}{2}=\frac{5}{6}DO$;
- in equilateral triangle $DBG$ line $UV$ is parallel to $BG$, hence 
  $DV=\frac{5}{6}DB=5\sqrt2$ and $UV=\frac{5}{2}\sqrt2$.

Comment: Well yes i know that's why i put that point V there, what i don't know is how far V is from B, and how much does the length of BO decreases after translated some units into V and change it into UV

Comment: See if my edit can help.

Comment: How did you get that DV = 5/6 DB ?

Comment: Triangles $DUV$ and $DOB$ are similar: $DV/DB=DU/DO=5/6$.

Comment: How to do the last side (Q'V) ? is it the height of BQ'D ?

Comment: No, draw a sketch of triangle $BVQ'$: you already know that $BV=\sqrt2$, $BQ'=3$ and $\angle VBQ'=45°$. Hence $VQ'=\sqrt5$

Comment: Thank you so much, im rather lagging on this one xD but i was able to keep up.

Answer (score 1):

It’s actually pretty straightforward.

Let $X$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Then, $ΔCEX$ is an isosceles triangle with side lengths

$$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}, \space \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}, \space \sqrt{3},$$

assuming a unit cube.

The angle between the two planes is just $\lambda=\angle{ECX}$, because $CE$ is normal to the plane $BDG$ due to $xyz$-symmetry and $CX$ is normal to $BFPQ$ due to $CX⊥BQ$ and $BFPQ$‘s vertical orientation.

Thus, from the dimensions of the isosceles triangle given above,

$$\cos\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$$

Comment: Thanks, i would like to know how to do this with line of intersection, because drawing normal line of a plane sometimes isn't easy

Comment: Well i know that by extending the plane to the outside the cube, but i dont want to deal with length outside cubes, it's rather hard and you would need to kind of guess the length for that, so i choose to translate plane instead.